# How to tell which image file is being used as Wallpaper in Wallch

Tags: desktop-background, appearance

I've just installed Wallch, and  it's working wonderfully.  I have set the program to cycle a huge number of images all within a folder on my computer.  There are so many images that I've forgotten about many of the ones popping up! I'm like to look into what they are.

Is there any way to tell which image is currently my background? I'd expect the answer to be in some linux code I' unfamiliar with, or a hidden feature of Wallch.

I found nothing in the Wallch GUI nor the Appearance settings.  I'm running Ubuntu 12.4 and Wallch 3.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
notify-send -i "terminal" "current-background" "$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri)"
```

generally you can get current wallpaper location by this command entered in a shell `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri`

Comment: just what i was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I just want to inform you that we have released a PPA for the 3+ versions of Wallch, which supports opening the folder of the current image set as background (under the 'File' menu or via the indicator). Also it has more features and bug fixes. If you want to install it, please run the following things through a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wallch/3+
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wallch
```

This will install the newest version of Wallch and will let you updated with any other newer versions!

Comment: Thank you very much! The automatic updates will be helpful, indeed! However, the feature doesn't sound like what I need.  All the wallpapers are in the same folder, so although it opens the folder of the current wallpaper, it also opens the folder of the other 250+ images.  @shinnra 's code worked nicely for just letting me know what image was being used.

Comment: Ok, use what it works best for you :)